# Angular Filter have an object which shows up in all cases

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects which looks like this:

```
$scope.endDimensions = [
        {'size':'all', 'label':'None', 'value':'none:0'},
        {'size':'3', 'label':'6" 90 Deg Std', 'value':'390DegStd:6'},
        {'size':'5', 'label':'4" 90 Deg Tie', 'value':'390DegTie:4'}
];
```

And a filter which looks like this:

```
<option ng-repeat="dimension in endDimensions | filter:{size:slab.size || slab.size=='all'}:true" value="{{dimension.value}}">{{dimension.label}}</option>
```

I'm trying to get the `none` to be an option no matter which size is chosen, the filter i'm using isn't working, it only show's the `none` option if no size is chosen.  I'm not sure the correct syntax for a filter like this?

Comment: I've always found Angular's filter expressions to be complicated and unintuitive, making them difficult to work with. Have you tried performing the filtering using plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including a `none` option in your array, can you just hardcode an `<option>` tag?

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.slab = {
    "size": 3
  };

  $scope.endDimensions = [{
    'size': '3',
    'label': '6" 90 Deg Std',
    'value': '390DegStd:6'
  }, {
    'size': '5',
    'label': '4" 90 Deg Tie',
    'value': '390DegTie:4'
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  Slab size:
  <input type="number" ng-model="slab.size" />

  <br/>
  <br/>

  <select>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option ng-repeat="dimension in endDimensions | filter:{size:slab.size}" value="{{dimension.value}}">{{dimension.label}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="slab.size" />
    <select>
      <option value="none:0">None</option>
      <option ng-repeat="dimension in endDimensions | filter:{size:slab.size || slab.size=='all'}:true" value="{{dimension.value}}">{{dimension.label}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', []);
      app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.endDimensions = [
          {'size':'3', 'label':'6" 90 Deg Std', 'value':'390DegStd:6'},
          {'size':'5', 'label':'4" 90 Deg Tie', 'value':'390DegTie:4'}
        ];
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It should be a hard-coded `<option>` tag. Notice I removed the "none" item from the array.